# FTP Monitoring issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I have windows 2003 and 2008 installed on my hosting server.
In my office there is a 2 internet line with static IPs.

When some one upload files on server I have checked the FTP log it shows my static ips.
Is it any ways to find out the local IP of my office system the file is uploaded.

If any one has a answer it will be great for me to trace out who is changing files on server. From last one month suddenly anytime one broken link is added in my sites home page and due to this my site is down.

Please help me to trace out the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Jagat Sheth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your office is using [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to share your static IPs with the computers in your local network. If that's the case, it's very unlikely you'll be able to trace back from the FTP log on your server to the private IP address within your local network.

To make it possible to identify the source of changes in future, you could configure multiple user accounts on your FTP server and give each staff member a different username and password. The FTP server should be able to keep track of which user logs in at which time. Permissions can be managed by using groups.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, Is it possible to trace out from which local system the file is uploaded?

Comment: There would be no record of the FTP transfer. But you may be able to find the bad file which was uploaded.

Comment: There are so many users here I am not able to create multiple accounts for each users. I have to find out local system ip from where the file is uploaded. File zila FTP client is used for upload files, is there any way to find out from local FTP client log?

Comment: It is possible to turn on FileZilla client logging, but it is not enabled by default. Even if it were enabled, if you have a malicious user they could just turn off logging for the period of their malfeasance, or use a different FTP client.